# Using ES's UpdateByQueryRequestBuilder with Rest High Level Client

Tags: java, elasticsearch

In Elasticsearch v5.5, we have used Transport Client when defining 
UpdateByQueryRequestBuilder and it worked fine:

```
UpdateByQyeryRequestBuilder updateByQuery = UpdateByQueryAction.INSTANCE
                                                  .newRequestBuilder(transportClient);
```

Since we're upgrading to use RestHighLevelClient, the above builder no longer works and it has this as error: "The method newRequestBuilder(ElasticsearchClient) in the type UpdateByQueryAction is not applicable for the arguments (RestHighLevelClient)". 
Does anyone know if i can just simply cast it like below:

```
UpdateByQyeryRequestBuilder updateByQuery = UpdateByQueryAction.INSTANCE
                                                      .newRequestBuilder((ElasticsearchClient) restHighLevelClient);
```

or there should be some other way to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/6.5/java-rest-high-document-update-by-query.html). It looks like you should prepare request directly:

```
UpdateByQueryRequest request = new UpdateByQueryRequest("source1", "source2");
request.set...
```

and later execute the request:

```
BulkByScrollResponse bulkResponse = client.updateByQuery(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

I think `UpdateByQyeryRequestBuilder` is a class specific for the TransportClient only.

Comment: Thank you @Piotr, since my upgraded version is 6.4 instead of 6.5, that RestHighLevelClient does not offer updateByQuery. It is still forcing one to use TransportClient in this version if they want to do updateByQuery. I guess the workaround for me might be to do upsert on whole doc after search which is not too ideal